# How to get Double Click in notepad in Windows 8 to select the entire word / line of text and not stop at symbols such as -,+,% etc

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, notepad, selection, double-click

In Windows XP, when one double clicks on a word, the entire word is selected. This is also true for words with dashes as well as urls that have dashes or other characters.

For example: http://www.awebsite.com/great-pictures or run+jump

In Windows 8, and apparently in Windows 7, as is mentioned in this post and with more examples and no solution: http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/152934-notepad-double-click-behaviour.html, the selection stops right after the symbol or as I have seen in one instance, right before.

Does anyone know of any way to change this behavior for Windows notepad in Windows 8 and/or Windows 7--maybe a registry hack or something else...?

Comment: Notepad is a simple program: it's basically a menu, a multiline edit control, and an optional status bar. I'm not aware of any double-click related settings/hacks. For what is worth, you can press Shift+End to select everything from the cursor to the end of the current line. If you want to select the whole line you might want to press Home first in order to quickly reach the beginning. If there's just one line you can also press Ctrl+A (select all). As an alternative you can use WordPad or a third-party text editor.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know of Shift+End. That would be great for selecting URL's. Too bad there isn't a shortcut to select from the current position until a space, such as "Sara Jackson-Smith told", in which Jackson-Smith is selected with the cursor being before the J and even better, if that is selected even if the cursor was in the middle of the words Jackson-Smith. I posted this here figuring someone for sure would have an answer. Also, I wonder why this got changed from how it was in Windows XP and if maybe there is a connection there to get it work the same way in Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: Just wanted to add that copying the notepad.exe file from Windows XP to Windows 8 didn't solve the problem. So, it looks like it's the Windows OS that determines this behavior and not the actual program itself.

Comment: Yeah, the behavior is strictly related to the built-in edit control which core functionality is provided by the `comctl32.dll` library. For example, you can reproduce the same issue if you start `regedit` and create/edit a multi-string value. I did some tests, here are the results: http://pastebin.com/jEMfZqy3 As to why it happens, only Microsoft can answer. Here's a related question: [Where do I configure the default text selection behavior in Windows?](http://superuser.com/q/203163/289138)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Microsoft introduced this foolish behaviour after XP, and they have naturally neither listened to the complaints nor corrected the mistake.

Here is a little helper, although it is necessary to involve the keyboard:

- Doubleclick somewhere on the start of the text so the first part gets highlighted.
- Then press (and hold) <kbd>shift</kbd> while clicking on the end point of the text.

Bingo, the whole line is highlighted.

Comment: Doesn't actually solve the OP's question; he just wants double-click to work as it used to. (However I upvoted because someone had downvoted and I don't think this deserves a -1 rating.)