# Can I select a whole sentence / paragraph with a triple-click on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, text-editing, mouse-click

As a linguist I often have to switch back and forth between Mac and Windows environments. I find that for the sake of rapidly editing text for several hours a day, having the advantage to chose between 3 types of selection on the Mac makes my workflow faster.

However, when working on the PC environment (Windows 7), I find that I spend (or rather waste) a lot of time selecting "by hand" (meaning dragging from the first letter to the last) whole paragraphs (or whole sentences inside paragraphs).

What I am trying to do is go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

*Note: The triple-click isn't a "select all" action, it only selects a paragraph defined by a dot or a line break.*

*Note: This would ideally be a system setting to allow for many programs within the Windows environment to function this way. The programs I use are somewhat limited and there are no ways to just use another one.*

Comment: You should be able to implement this with AutoHotkey. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/28635-triple-click/

Answer (score 2):

How the mouse reacts to certain click-combinations is controlled by the applications.

I.E.:

- In Word you can click Ctrl+Click to select a sentence.
- In Wordpad (built into Windows) and Notepad++ triple-click = select line.

So I'd suggest getting/using a more feature-rich text editor than Notepad.exe, since it's intended to be as basic a text editor as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I added a note to explain that basically, I am working with text editors that are requested by client and that the change of behavior of the triple click should be system-wide if possible.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, it's up to the application to handle all but the most basic mouse actions. See this [related SU answer](http://superuser.com/a/610451/23133).

Comment: You should be able to implement this with AutoHotkey. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/28635-triple-click/

Comment: @uSlackr Free to add a AHK-based answer, only ensure that you provide real details, as I could see using AHK to perform this action could get really sticky on the actual action part (selecting a line/sentence).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. My solution was to use [EditPad Lite](https://www.editpadlite.com/), a free text editor for Windows.

[image]